# How to include LaTeX snippets directly in Doxygen comments?

Tags: latex, doxygen

I would like to be able to edit LaTeX parts of some Doxygen comments externally with some suitable editor. I would use that only for complex environments. To do that, I figured I can have LaTeX-only files and include them from Doxygen. I did create Doxygen aliases for `\begin` and `\end` to make the syntax compatible.

(For example, I know how to set-up Emacs/AUCTex for working with LaTeX snippets that have no preamble and document structure.)

Is there a way to include the contents of a .tex file inside a Doxygen comment? I look for something analogous to `\htmlinclude`, but for TeX files. Is there some way to emulate the functionality, given my requirements for having a TeX-only external source?

Comment: We now have a dedicated Q&A site for TeX questions. Please ask your question again at tex.stackexchange.com

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I'm trying to do the same - I've tried several variations on \include and \verbinclude, but I can't seem to get it working...

Comment: Sorry, but I couldn't find a way to do it at the time, even though I read through the documentation of Doxygen. The inquiry was for educational purposes, so I gave up eventually.

Answer (score 3):

You may use something like

```
\latexonly
\input <file>
\endlatexonly
```

where `<file>` is the path to the file to include, either absolute or relative to the directory in which the latex documentation is generated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [`\verbinclude`](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdverbinclude) command? This command includes any file verbatim in the documentation (in contrast to `\include`, which is used to include *source* files).

From the doxygen manual:

> `\verbinclude <file-name>`
>
> This command includes the file `<file-name>` verbatim in the documentation. The command is equivalent to pasting the file in the documentation and placing `\verbatim` and `\endverbatim` commands around it.
>
> Files or directories that doxygen should look for can be specified using the `EXAMPLE_PATH` tag of doxygen's configuration file.

**Edit**: I just had a thought that you may wish to strip the preamble from your .tex file before including the rest of the file in the documentation. you could do this using the `\dontinclude` command which, together with the `\line`, `\skip`, `\skipline`, and `\until` commands allows you to include specific lines/blocks of a particular file. See the example in the `\dontinclude` [documentation](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmddontinclude).

Comment: Thanks, but what I wanted was to have LaTeX macros working in the external document. For example, a diagram would be bulky, not to mention ugly, just sitting in the comments. I thought that such "complex" documentation can be put in some external file. But I have given up the idea now.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't quite understand your comment. The `\verbinclude` command includes the contents of external files in your documentation during the build of you documentation, this does not affect your source files.

Comment: Thanks, but verbinclude is not the solution. It suppresses LaTeX macros. All the code inside the LaTeX environments is emitted in source form. So, for example, if I wanted to draw a UML diagram with LaTeX, I would get the source markup on the page, not the picture I want.