# About latex formulas in doxygen

Tags: latex, doxygen

Every time I need to copy a latex paragraph and put it in my source code as a doxygen documentation, I need to put a **\f** next to each **$** and do other modifications.

Isn't there an easier way to tell doxygen that this whole paragraph contains only latex and thus should be fully interpreted as latex code?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears not to be possible to include LaTeX format `.tex` files directly. Depending on the complexity of the LaTeX files, a possibility would be to write a script which makes the required modifications. Related questions that give further background and suggestions are [How to include LaTeX snippets directly in Doxygen comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4881668/how-to-include-latex-snippets-directly-in-doxygen-comments) and [Including LaTeX documentation as comments in source code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124193/including-latex-documentation-as-comments-in-source-code). Please come back and answer if you find a good solution to this problem.

Comment: Thanks and sure I will get back to answer this if I find a solution.